# NSRangeException : "beyond bounds" error 

Tags: iphone, exception

I am working on a sqlite-based application in the database of which there is a field at index 2.

In this I am not saving any data but when I run that database on Firefox I see that the index 2  had a value -2147483648, and when I am trying to add a new cell in my subview by:

```
return [appDelegate.items count]+1;
```

I am getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (2)'

The variable at index 2 is of decimal type:-

```
NSInteger n = i.need;
```

and...

```
sqlite3_bind_int(updStmt, 2, n);
```

...is the default value coming in index 2.  Does this have to do anything with the exception?  If yes, how can I can correct it and if no then why is it happening?

Comment: what is the other code around `return [appDelegate.items count]+1;`, what method is it in? If there are two items in the array, then you cannot access index 2. You can only access index 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using access Specifier `%@` instead of `%d` while inserting or reading...
Use **intValue** for retriving or inserting.